# How to get document with reference fields populated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Consider posts document schema in firestore:

```
{
  user: "/users/userId", //reference to document in users collection
  description: "lorem ipsum" //string
}
```

how can I get this document with user field populated with referred document data?
this code `db.collection("posts").doc("postId").get().then(post => console.log(post))` returns post document.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to make a second query for the referenced document.  Fields with references are never automatically followed during a query.

Comment: It can be convenient to use in security rules when determining permissions of a document, or save you a line of code in constructing a reference to another document.  If you don't find a reference isn't helpful to you, then you don't have to use one.

Comment: @NodirNasirov "what is the point of having reference then?" -> You might be interesting by watching this episode of #AskFirebase (starting at 272 seconds): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Elg2zDVIcLo&t=272s